# How do I export numeric data with JSON:API?

Tags: 9

All the data exported is formatted with a string. Enclosed with quotes.

I'd like *excluded_id* to be numeric. The current state is the following.

```json
[
 {
  "pending_id": "1234",
  "excluded_id": "111",
}]
```

I'd like the format to be the following.

```json
[
 {
  "pending_id": 1234,
  "excluded_id": 111,
}]
```

The JSON service is implemented as a [REST plugin](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview). The normalizer is the following.

```php
use Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\NormalizerBase;

class CBIBondTableDataNormalizer extends NormalizerBase {
  protected $supportedInterfaceOrClass = 'Drupal\cbi_dms_data\data\model\CBIBondTableResultData';

  public function normalize($object, $format = NULL, array $context = []) {
   return $object->normalize();
  }
}
```

With the normalizer.

```php
class MyTableResultData implements MyTableResultType {

  public $row = [];

  public function __construct() {}

  public function addSqlResult($object) {
    $result = new CBIBondTableResult($object);
    $this->row[] = $result;
  }

  public function normalize() {
    $output = [];
    foreach ($this->row as $currentRow) {
      $output[] = (object) $currentRow;
    }
    return $output;
  }
}
```

I've tried setting the type in `MyTableResultData`.

```php
public int $PendingID;
```

This doesn't work as PHP 7 doesn't allow something to be an integer or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the value to integer helps

```
$int_value = intval($value);
if (strval($int_value) == $value) {
  $value = $int_value;
}
$this->$key_camel = $value;
```

I wrote it this way as I was concerned with null. Doesn't seem to be a problem.